# Predict / Forecast exchange rate based on finacial indicators

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, forecasting

This is the dataset. I want to create a time series to forecast the last row (EURUSD).

Is it possible to forecast the last variable based on the other financial indicators present in the dataset?

[image]

Comment: add your question in stackexchange!

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple linear regression for the prediction. [image]

With your independent variables(interest rate, etc.) you can find the dependent variable(EURUSD in your case).

For further instructions and how to write it, you can visit these links;

[Basic One](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-multiple-linear-regression-using-python/)

[More intuitive](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2022/03/multiple-linear-regression-using-python/)